# EMR Cluster Configuration Property regarding EMRFS Consistent View

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

I have an EMR Cluster. The cluster has a set of properties. One of the properties of the cluster includes fs.s3.consistent set as true. What does this signify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fs.s3.consistent` is the main property that switches the [EMRFS Consistent View](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-plan-consistent-view.html) feature on or off. (It's off by default.)

This entire feature is no longer necessary ever since [the announcement that S3 now has strong read-after-write consistency](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-strong-read-after-write-consistency/).